# Text alignment in HTML table column through VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to draft one Outlook mail body with html table using Excel VBA.

I am able to draft the mail with table and data. I am not able to align the text in the amount column as right alignment.

How do I align the text in the amount column to right?

```vb
Dim strTableHeader As String
Dim strTableBody As String
itb="abc"
balance=1000
strTableHeader = "<font size=3 face=" & Chr(34) & "Arial" & Chr(34) & "><b>" & _
                    "<tr bgcolor=lightblue>" & _
                        TD("ITB") & _
                        TD("Balance Amount") & _
                    "</tr></b></font>"

strTableBody= strTableBody & strTableHeader
strTableBody = strTableBody & _
                      "<tr>" & _
                          TD(itb) & _
                          TD(balance) & _
                      "</tr>"
```

I am using this in my mail sending procedure:

```vb
Sub sendmailmdl()
    DoEvents
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With objMail
         
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>"  & strTableBody & " </BODY></HTML>" 
        
        .Display
        DoEvents
         
    End With
End Sub
```

where

```
TD(strIn As String) As String TD = "<TD nowrap>" & strIn & "</TD>" End Function
```

Comment: What does TD() do? Perhaps pass an align to it? Or set a class and add a style

Comment: Function TD(strIn As String) As String
    TD = "<TD nowrap>" & strIn & "</TD>"
End Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
tbody tr td:nth-child(2) { text-align: right; }
```

to your stylesheet

or pass a second parameter to TD() to add

```
style="text-align: right; white-space:nowrap"
```

to the cell